# Find and replace slashes with new linfeed in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

Can anyone tell me how to replace a slash (/) with a linefeed in Excel 2010? I have a very long worksheet with words, origins, and definitions. In the origins column, some rows show multiple places seperated by slashes. I want each item in the cell to be on a new line within the cell. Is this possible?

Right now the cell looks like this

Roman/ Celtic/ Baltic

I want the cell to look like this

Roman
  Celtic
  Baltic

Answer (score 2):

- select your cells
- right click, `Format Cell`s   ... goto the *Alignment* tab,and check `Wrap Text` (Pic 1)
- press [ctrl](/questions/tagged/ctrl)[f](/questions/tagged/f) together
- goto the *Replace* tab
- under `Find What` enter "/"
- goto `Replace With` then press [alt](/questions/tagged/alt)[0010](/questions/tagged/0010)
- `Replace All` (Pic 2)

**Pic 1**
[image: Pic 1]

**Pic 2**
[image: Pic 2]

Comment: Thanks brettdj for the great example... unfortunately it does not work... it only removes the slashes... I have tried it several times and checked to make sure everything was set as you have shown... No Go... won't work for me...

Comment: Use Alt+0010 instead (hold Alt all the way)

Answer (score 0):

As another option, here's some VBA code to make a new function that will convert / to LF:

```
Public Function SlashToLF(oldstring As String) As String
    Dim newString As String
    Dim c As Long

    For c = 1 To Len(oldstring)
        If Mid(oldstring, c, 1) = "/" Then
            newString = newString & vbNewLine
        Else
            newString = newString & Mid(oldstring, c, 1)
        End If
    Next
    slashtolf = newString

End Function
```

If you put the formula `=SlashToLF(A1)` in another cell you'll get the new version with linefeeds.  You can then Copy/Paste As Values over your original if you like.  Also, you will need to format the cell as Wrap Text for it to work.